# .net Decode SMTP Email Content

Tags: .net, smtp, decode

I'm trying to integrate an online API http://www.brandmymail.com/docs/http/api_methods/rfc2rfc with a CRM database that has it's own email delivery mechanisms.  The API gives me an encoded email back, I need to strip out the encoding and just keep the HTML part of the email.

The API documentation says the encoding is https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2822

Is there anything in the .net framework that will convert a raw encoded email to it's en-encoded state?

Comment: How are you getting the email message? And can you give an example of the encoded text? No good answer can be given without seeing what you want decoded because nobody will be able to confirm their solution works... Additionally the RFC you linked for encoding specifically says "In addition, this standard does not specify an encoding of the characters for either transport or storage".

Comment: Perhaps this might help: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/11882/Advanced-MIME-Parser-Creator-Editor

Comment: Here's the file content http://www.filedropper.com/emailbodyleepirouet